# Add new property to a document in DocumentDB with nodejs

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I have a JSON document in DocumentDB.

I wish to add new data to a given document.

For example.

Current document:

```
{
    "User": "ABC",
    "UserID": "123"
}
```

New document

```
{
    "User": "ABC",
    "Height":"1.60",
    "UserID": "123"
}
```

I have tried solutions such as mentioned here:

[Add new properties to DocumentDB Document in Stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31821031/add-new-properties-to-documentdb-document-in-stored-procedure)

But I get "getContext is not defined".

I believe the issue is that I am unsure of how to call a document via a function.

I would like:

```
var documentURL = "dbs/'dbname'/colls/'collsname'/docs/'docsname'"
editDocument(documentURL)

function editDocument(document) {
    var collection = getContext().getCollection();
    var response = getContext().getResponse();

    document.Height = "1.60";

    collection.createDocument(collection.getSelfLink(), document, function(err, result) {
    if(err) throw err;

       // Return the resulting document back as the response.
       response.setBody(result);
    });
}
```

Should I use client.replaceDocument instead, or maybe there is a better way to do this.

The issue may be that the function is plainly trying to use the text location "dbs/colls/docs" in the function rather than the document itself.

Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: You need to actually upload the stored procedure to Cosmos and call it there. getContext is specific to that runtime environment you can't just run it in a random node script

Comment: I see, is there a way to edit documents without stored procedures?

Comment: No, unless you use a Stored Procedure you're only able to Create, Upsert, or Replace entire documents. You won't be able to modify individual properties

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to use `replaceDocument` instead.

```
var documentURL = "dbs/'dbname'/colls/'collsname'/docs/'docid'"

client.readDocument(documentURL, (err, doc) => {
    if(err) return console.log(err);

    doc.Height = "1.60";

    client.replaceDocument(documentUrl, doc, (err, result) => {
        if(err) return console.log(err);
        console.log('replaced document');
    });
});
```

Comment: Awesome this worked great thanks! Is it easy to order where in the list of properties the new one should go?

Comment: You shoud order the properties programmatically before you call `replaceDocument` methed.

Comment: Hi, sorry new to this, what to you mean programmatically? Set doc.currentProperty1 = "";, doc.currentProperty2 = ""; like that?

Comment: Or better still, can i not specify 'doc.abc = "123" ' after doc.abc1 - the reason is I have multiple scripts that will want to add to the document - to do so with the current method I would need to specify a strict order for each script to add the document.

Comment: Now your question is about ordering properties of the object in Javascript. It has nothing to do with DocumentDB SDK.